# How to make nuget create folders in the project?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

Is there a way to add specific folders in the project that the package is installed?

For example, according to this [blogpost](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx) you can add multiple files to the project, but what I want to add are folders. I added folders in the content folder before I create my nuget package, but the folders are not added to the project after the package is installed.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried to add an empty folder? Because nuget only creates directories in the project if the folder was not empty in the content directory. Try to put inside an empty placeholder file.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a directory hierarchy in the content folder, nuget will replicate that in your project.

Comment: To add to this, here is a [link](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory) to the documentation discussing the use of the content folder.